# Examples of how to transform a random variable with a distribution not Gaussian to a random variable with Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

My doubt is if there exists a method to transform a random variable with not Gaussian distribution in other with a Gaussian distribution.

I only found a random variable with Birhaum Saunders distribution that I can transform in Gaussian.

I would like to obtain other examples.

Comment: In practice, I suppose the goal would be to use uniform random variables output by a (pseudo)random generator, to get random variables that are standard normal.  One fairly accurate method is to add 12 independent random variables from UNIF(0,1) and subtract 6 from the total to get one standard normal observation. Another is the 'Box-Muller' method which has nice explanations on Wikipedia and elsewhere online. It uses two indep. uniform observations as input and gets two indep standard normal observations as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a continuous random variable $X$ with distribution function $F_X(X)$, that you know what it is, then the random variable

$$Y=\sigma \Phi^{-1}[F_X(X)] + \mu \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$$

where $\Phi()^{-1}$ is the inverse standard Normal distribution function.

Since this is the standard way of generating draws from a Normal Distribution (since $F_X(X)\sim U(0,1)$), I wonder whether this is what you are really asking here.

Comment: You don't address non-existence of $\Phi,$ much less $\Phi^{-1},$ in closed form.

Answer (score 1):

**Add 12 Uniforms.** Demonstration in R:

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{12}$ be independently $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$
and let $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{12} X_i - 6.$ Then $Z \stackrel{aprx}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$ Each $X_i$ has $E(X_i) = 1/2, Var(X_i) = 1/12,$ so
$E(Z) = 0$ and $Var(Z) = 1.$ By the Central Limit Theorem, $Z$ is very
nearly normal. The main flaw is that the method never produces $|Z|>6.$

In the demonstration below $m = 1000$ standard normal observations produced
by this method pass a Shapiro-Wilk normality test and their histogram
seems a close match to the standard normal density function.

```
set.seed(821);  m = 1000
z = replicate(m,  sum(runif(12))-6)
shapiro.test(z)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  z
W = 0.99817, p-value = 0.3615   # P-value > .05, so no evidence of non-normality

hist(z, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x), -5, 5, add=T)
```

[image]

**Box-Muller:** Let $X_1, X_2$ be independently $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$
Then 
$$Z_1 = \sqrt{-2\log(X_1)}\cos(2\pi X_2)\;\;\text{and}\;\;
Z_2 = \sqrt{-2\log(X_1)}\sin(2\pi X_2)$$
are independently $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$

Theoretically, the $Z_i$ are exactly standard normal. This method is discussed at length in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform).

A computational flaw is that trig and log functions can underflow system capabilities and not produce
$|Z|$ greater than about $7,$ depending on the software.

In the demonstration below $m = 1000$ standard normal observations produced
by this method pass a Shapiro-Wilk normality test and their histogram
seems a close match to the standard normal density function.

```
set.seed(822)
u1 = runif(500);  u2 = runif(500)
z1 = sqrt(-2*log(u1))*cos(2*pi*u2)
z2 = sqrt(-2*log(u1))*sin(2*pi*u2)
z = c(z1, z2)
shapiro.test(z)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  z
W = 0.99818, p-value = 0.3672

hist(z, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x), -5, 5, add=T)
```

[image]

**Wichura method:**  Let $\Phi$ denote the standard normal CDF.
If $\Phi$ were expressible in closed form and were invertable, then
$Z = \Phi^{-1}(U) \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ for $U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$

Although $\Phi$ is not expressible in closed form [Wichura (1988)](http://csg.sph.umich.edu/abecasis/gas_power_calculator/algorithm-as-241-the-percentage-points-of-the-normal-distribution.pdf) constructed a
rational approximation to $\Phi$ that is accurate to the limits of double-precision arithmetic, and he also found a similarly accurate approximation to $\Phi^{-1}.$
In R statistical software the function `rnorm` uses Wichura's inverse to
generate standard normal observations from standard uniform ones produced by
the Mersenne-Twister pseudorandom generator. Some technical fine-tuning
aside, `rnorm(10)` essentially uses `qnorm(runif(10))` to produce ten independent standard
normal observations.

```
set.seed(818);  z = rnorm(1000)
shapiro.test(z)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  z
W = 0.99877, p-value = 0.732

hist(z, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x), -5, 5, add=T)
```

[image]